# jquery datatable default editing on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatable plugin on my web application, with inline editing functionality. The default editing setup

```
$('#example').dataTable().makeeditable({
          null  //default editing
    });
```

only triggers the edit event once Enter button is pressed. Is there a way this can be changed to a 'click outside the box' event similar to how the select works

```
$('#example').dataTable().makeeditable({
          indicator: 'Saving...',
          tooltip: 'Click to select option',
          loadtext: 'loading...',
          type: 'select',
          onblur: 'submit',
          data: "{'A; A':'B; B'}"                                    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jeditable might be the ideal solution. Please check out the example [here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html).